# When can we use a z-test instead of a binomial test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, z-test

I read from
https://www.spss-tutorials.com/binomial-test/
and noticed that

"So when can we use a z-test instead of a binomial test? A rule of thumb is that P0*n and (1 - P0)*n must both be > 5, where P0 denotes the hypothesized population proportion and n the sample size."

I really couldn't find any reliable source to validate such rule of thumb.
Could someone please explain the logic behind this? Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

I will approach this issue by showing results of the normal approximation to a binomial probability in one unfavorable case
and then in a more favorable case.

**Rule of thumb violated:** Suppose $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p=1/4)$ and we seek $P(X \le 1),$
The exact answer from the binomial PDF formula or from R software is
$P(X \le 1) = 0.7383,$ to four places.

```
pbinom(1, 4, 1/4)
[1] 0.7382812
```

Your rule of thumb fails because $np = 1 < 5,$ But let's try to use the
normal approximation (with continuity correction) anyhow, to see the result.
First, $\mu = np = 1$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{3/4} = 0.8660.$
Then,

$$P(X \le 1) = P(X < 1.5) = 
P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < \frac{1.5-1}{0.8660}\right)\\
\approx P(Z <  0.5774) = 0.7182.$$
or 0.7180 if you round to use printed standard normal tables.

In the graph below, the exact binomial probability is the sum of the heights
of the two vertical bars to the left of the dotted line at $x = 1.5.$
The approximating normal probability is the area beneath the normal curve
to the left of that line.

[image]

A major difficulty is that there is considerable area under the normal curve
to the left of 0, where there can be no binomial probability. Many rules of
thumb are contrived to prevent such large areas under the approximating
normal curve to the left of 0 or to the right of $n.$ A rule specifically targeted for this is $\min[np/(1-p), n(1-p)/p] > 3.$ (No rule of thumb is perfect, but the [one you are using](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207671/normal-approximation-to-the-binomial-distribution-why-np5) is not bad and is widely used.)

**Rule of thumb met:** If we change the problem to finding $P(X \le 10)$ for 
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(40, 1/4),$ then the exact binomial
probability is 0.5839 and the normal approximation is 0.5724.
Now, the rule of thumb is satisfied. But the normal approximation
would be still better if $p$ were nearer to $1/2$ or $n$ were larger.
(Except for very large $n$ and $p \approx 1/2,$ one cannot routinely expect more than
about two places of accuracy from a normal approximation.

```
pbinom(10, 40, .25)
[1] 0.5839041
pnorm(10.5, 10, sqrt(10*.75)) 
[1] 0.5724339
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The binomial test is what's called an "exact test", meaning we look at the exact probability of observing a result as extreme or more extreme than the one we have observed provided the null is true.

The z-test for the binomial proportion is derived from maximum likelihood estimates, which make assumptions about how much data you have.  Essentially, given "enough" (whatever that means) data the sampling distribution of the maximum likelihood estimator for the mean of a binomial distribution is approximately normally distributed, leading to the z-test.

Those inequalities are likely some way of ensuring that there is enough data to justify the normal approximation.